# Feedback on my clip

Tags: feedback, websites, sound-design, promotion

Hello sound designers! Please give me some feedback on my work. It's a intro/promo clip for my site [Cvrgoje Sound](http://cvrgoje.com).

Here is the clip http://www.cvrgoje.com/demo

Also you can find it on YouTube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjsNjgnP5_s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice work! I like it.

Comment: Glad that you like it :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds are good but shouldn't the clip show off more of your work you've done to sync?

Comment: it is not demo-reel

Comment: Thought it was :) It does say demo in the domain name and button the site though.